# How to list available users in PostgreSQL having only the data directory?

Tags: postgresql, users, password-recovery, datadir

I messed up a bit with a Dockerized PostgreSQL instance and accidentally overwrote the values I had for `POSTGRES_USER` and `POSTGRES_PASSWORD`. They were randomly generated, so guessing them is basically out of the question. By nature of Dockerized PostgreSQL, if you specify your own username, the role `postgres` will not be created. That means that `postgres`, `admin`, `root` are all invalid roles on my DB instance.

Now I'm stuck with a data directory in a volume that I can access and a `psql` that I cannot access because I don't know any valid username on that database. Is there a list of usernames in this data directory that I can somehow access to get inside and change the password?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I found a way. According to [PostgreSQL docs on the structure of the data directory](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/storage-file-layout.html):

> | Item | Description |
> | --- | --- |
> | `global` | Subdirectory containing cluster-wide tables, such as `pg_database` |

So I connected to the container running the DB with `docker exec -it <container-name> /bin/sh` and went to `/var/lib/postgresql/data/global`. There were a bunch of binary files, and I started printing their contents one-by-one until I found a string that I recognized. It was found in file `1260`, though I doubt that's going to be the case all the time.

Then I simply connected to the database (the Docker version of the database is configured in such a way that you don't need a password to connect from within) using `psql -U <recovered-username>` and changed the password with `\password '<recovered-username>'`. Success!

Comment: The number will always be 1260, unless you run `VACUUM (FULL)` on `pg_authid`. A simpler way would have been to start PostgreSQL in single-user mode.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe thanks for this addition. I wanted to run the database in single-user mode, but in doing so I had to first stop the original PostgreSQL process, but in the Docker version that process is PID 1, and stopping it somehow stopped the container as well

Comment: You could start it outside the container, you just need the data directory and PostgreSQL installed.

Answer (score -1):

Saving it in clear text anywhere, would defeat the point of the passwords !!!

Your only option is to Save what you can and reinstall.  This time use GIT or something to keep successive backups of important files.